# Returning formatted json querying a tree with two different relationships (cypher)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a tree-like structure involving "Blocks", which are connected to other Blocks by "NEXT_BLOCK" or "BLOCK_CHILD". A node can have at most one BLOCK_CHILD and one NEXT_BLOCK, and this can recursively repeat itself.

[image: node structure]

While I can get all the blocks from the starter node simply by running the following cypher, I would like to get the data in a specific data format.

```
MATCH (n:Node {id: $nodeId})-[r:NEXT_BLOCK|BLOCK_CHILD*0..]-(b:BLOCK_ELEMENT|BLOCK_INLINE)
RETURN n, r, b
```

I need to efficiently get this tree of data as an array where each 'Next block' is the next element in the array, while everything that's part of 'BLOCK_CHILD' (including its next nodes) is encapsulated within a children field which is also an array. So the example above would be given as

```
[
  {
  id : "4fa9125.."
  children : [{text: ""}]
  }, 
  {
  id : "66fb771.."
  children : [
                    {
                      id: "466a6a"
                      children: [{id: "5498a3"}]
                    },
                    {
                      id: "90753..."
                      children: []
                    },
              ]
  }, 
  {
  id : "12258d5.."
  children : [{id: "97b56a"}]
  }, 
]
```

The organisation can still change if my nodes have a better structural design. These need to be correctly ordered and the order will frequently change though.

I appreciate the help!

I've tried using APOC.convertToTree as an example below.

```
MATCH path = (n {id: "eecd1592-d41b-4b3c-aaa1-16562d808ecc"})-[r:BLOCK_CHILD|NEXT_BLOCK*0..]->(p)
WITH collect(path) AS paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths)
YIELD value
RETURN value;
```

I've also tried some structural changes such as storing the json object, but as it frequently is changed and blocks are consistently cross referenced I didn't want to simply store the entire content as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I did an export like this, I used [`apoc.export.json.query`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.export/apoc.export.json.query/). That procedure uses results from a query and exports it as JSON. Depending on your desired JSON format, you may need to run a couple tools to remove extra escape characters and such (tr, sed, or something). I believe I ran `tr -d '\' file` on it to remove extra backslashes.